# Debugging a autotools project library

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, autotools

Platform: Debian

I have a project which builds ( using ./configure --enable-debug ).
When I run the project in a debugger it is using a library in /usr/lib instead of the one built by the project.

How can I get the executable to load the projects version of the lib?

Comment: take a look at the linking stage to see what it is using. I haven't seen the make, I can't help you any further.

Comment: What is the library you are compiling? What is the library that gets linked instead?

Comment: @sturmer, the one that it links against is an installed production  version. The one that I want to load is the built in the project directory ( with debug info in it ).

Comment: @Mouse.The.Lucky.Dog Have you tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory where the library is built? The content of that variable is checked before the /usr and /usr/lib directories.

Comment: How are you loading the executable into the debugger? Hopefully it looks like `libtool --mode=execute gdb ./myprogram`. Libtool will take care of loading libraries from the proper place and then invoke gdb.